# Countable infinite support of probabilistic measure

Tags: probability-theory

Let $E\subset\Omega$ be a countable infinite set.

I want to define probability measure $p$ on $\Omega$, such that $p(x)>0 \iff x\in E$ and all $x\in E$ have the same probability. Is that possible? What is probability of single $x\in E$ then?

Comment: "Countable" technically includes finite, and for finite non-empty $E$ it is certainly possible. For countably infinite, it is not, because of countable additivity.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is finite then the probability of each element is just $1/|E|$. Otherwise it is not possible.

To show this, put $E=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots\}$. Assign the probability $p_k>0$ to each $x_k$.

Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k=1$$
that is, the series whose term is $p_k$ converges. This implies that $p_k\to0$, and this is not possible if $\{p_k\}$ is a constant positive sequence.

Comment: so this article is incorrect. i mean author assumes that probability doesnt satisfy countable additivity: http://www.fep.up.pt/docentes/joao/material/research/disagree.pdf